# What's the correct way to query accross multiple entity contexts without the chance of too-long IN clause being generated?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to produce the set of entities to be created in a target context by comparing IDs from a second context.

This is what I came up with but I'm looking for a better way or confirmation this is the right way.

The main points I've noted so far are:

- ToList() is requred to prevent an error occurring when a query uses
  multiple contexts
- I know that if I force an IN clause into the generated SQL there's an upper limit to how many it can handle and I don't want that error condition looming.

  ```
  public override IEnumerable<Campaign> Execute()
  {
      using (var eom = eomDatabase.Create())
      using (var cake = cakeEntities.Create())
      {
          var campaigns = eom.Campaigns.Select(c => c.pid).ToList();
          var offers = cake.CakeOffers.Select(c => c.Offer_Id).ToList();
          var newOffers = offers.Except(campaigns).ToList();
          var newCampaigns = from offer in cake.CakeOffers
                             where newOffers.Contains(offer.Offer_Id)
                             select new Campaign {
                                 pid = offer.Offer_Id,
                                 campaign_name = offer.OfferName
                             };

          return newCampaigns.ToList();
      }
  }
  ```

**UPDATE**: apparently let statements do not work how I thought - the above produces no error while my original code causes a multiple contexts error.

```
    var newCampaigns = from offer in cake.CakeOffers 
                       let campaigns = eom.Campaigns.Select(c => c.pid).ToList() 
                       let offers = cake.CakeOffers.Select(c => c.Offer_Id).ToList() 
                       let newOffers = offers.Except(campaigns).ToList() 
                       where newOffers.Contains(offer.Offer_Id) 
                       select new Campaign { 
                           pid = offer.Offer_Id, 
                           campaign_name = offer.OfferName 
                       };
```

Comment: My gut sense tells me that EF will generate an ugly query. I hope I am wrong. I'd do it iterational.

Comment: what do you use to debug as you iterate, i.e. see the query it generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The impact of ToList() is to have the query executed at that point. Therefore, you are pulling all the Ids into memory. Depending on the relative sizes of the data sets this may or may not be optimal. If there are more campaigns than cake offers, you may be better off querying the cake offer id's into memory first using a cakeEntities context - then dispose of it and manage the rest separately.

You can easily circumvent any IN clause limitations by batching your reading of cake offers - just handle a fixed number at a time using the Take operator: e.g.

```
IList<int> cakeOffers;

using (var cakeDb = new cakeEntities())
{
    cakeOffers = cakeDb.CakeOffers.Take(10).Select(c => c.pid).ToList();        
}
```

2) (EDIT - I think you knew this...) You aren't actually creating any new Campaigns in the context. You're just contructing a bunch of them in memory. You need to add them to the context and then save it to create them.

EDIT

I would then just query the eomDatabase for existing Campaigns with matching offer_Ids using a Contains clause: e.g.:

```
var existingCampaignOffers = campaignDb.Campaigns
    .Where(co => cakeOffers.Contains(co.Offer_Id)).Select(c => c.Offer_Id).ToList();
```

Then finally use Except() in memory to get the exclusive list Offer_Ids you need to create your new Campaigns.

Comment: that's very cool to know that Take can be used to batch in that way - i never would have thought of it

Comment: Yes - you'd need to either remove the offers from the db or mark them as done when you've processed them of course.